# How do I get min, max and total values from database table sorting by category and putting results in new table?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

I have a table **[Feedback]** that consist of *Id, Name, Type and Score*.

*There are 5 different types [Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5] and each type has different numbers of scores.*

Now, **I need to display minimum, maximum and total score for each type**. Should I create a new table (Type, MinScore, MaxScore, Total) and try to bind the data or is there a way to create that table with calculated values during the runtime?

I`m using C# in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? Also you do not need to store this Min, Max values, you just need queries to pull this information at run time. Storing this Min, max and total values will make your database messy.

Comment: I`m using VisualStudio LocalDB feature, so I`m assuming its SQL. I know there are SQL functions Sum() Min() and Max() but my problem at this point how should I tell the compiler to create those 3 values but for each different Type and display it in GridView maybe or.. ?

Comment: This is my statement to show all the values from DB to user: SELECT [Name], [Type], [Score] FROM [FeedBackForms] ORDER BY [Score] DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need a very basic query to get the results you are looking for.

```
SELECT [Name]
     , [Type]
     , MAX([Score])  Maximum_Value 
     , MIN([Score])  Minimum_Value
     , SUM([Score])  Total_Value
FROM [FeedBackForms] 
GROUP BY [Name]
       , [Type]
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. You just made my day! Any blogs/tutorials you could recommend on this topic?

Comment: Just simply google how to use MIN, MAX and any aggregate functions in SQL and there is plenty of material online.